# Trying to Build url path through DetailView , but am getting duplicate values in html page

Tags: python, html, django, django-views, detailview

I am starting to learn django.  I want to create a directory site.

I want it to be: home page -> list of States -> List of Restaurant Types -> List of Restaurant names

I have 'list of States' as a generic.ListView and it works perfect. I tried making 'List of Restaurant Types' as a ListView as well but it wouldn't pull any data in the html. Changing it to a DetailView it pulls the data but has duplicate entries. Is there a way to restrict it as unique outputs in either views.py or the restaurant_detail.html?

The current html code is:

```
<p><b>Restaurant SECTION</b></p>
{% for name in states.restaurant_name_set.all %}
<p>{{name.restaurant_types}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

I get something like:

Fine Dining
Buffet
Buffet
Buffet
Food Truck

I want just one of each I can then link to go to a list of Restaurant Names

Comment: Pleas share your *models* and the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use extra input parameters, just use the "ifchanged" Django built-in filter: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#ifchanged

```
{% for name in states.restaurant_name_set.all|dictsort:'restaurant_name' %}
    <p>{% ifchanged %}{{name.restaurant_types}}{% endifchanged %}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you for helping! Django has been a steep hill but I am slowly putting it together. It did not work with the 'dictsort' maybe due to how my models are. I will look up what that does to troubleshoot further!